# C++, cin.get(); not working

Tags: c++

I don't understand when I run this in Visual Studio 2013 why the run window goes away. So to compensate for that I put in a cin.get(); but it's still not working. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Mind it, I'm very new to C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 0;

    cout << "How old are you? \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << a;
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: print a newline after the cout << a. Also try getchar() instead of cin.get()

Comment: Neither of them seem to work. I've tried adding a blank line after and also replacing cin.get() with getchar().

Comment: I tried in gcc (linux) . It works for me. How do you run it in VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your input is a number, the line

```
cin >> a;
```

reads the number and leaves the newline character in the input stream. When the line

```
cin.get();
```

is executed, the newline character is read and discarded. Hence, the program doesn't wait for any further input. It executes the next line, returns from `main` and the program finishes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
   `system("PAUSE")` 
after cout.